# SQL: cell entries to matrix

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table with entries representing cells on a matrix with x, y cordinates and the value for that position like this:

```
COL1   COL2    COL3
....   ....   ......
y1      x1    value11
y1      x2    value12
y1      x3    value13
y2      x1    value21
y2      x3    value23
```

All columns are Integer values and only COL3 has unique constraint. I want a report from this table in matrix form where both the number of columns and nuber of rows can vary, like this:

```
COL1   X1       X2       X3
..     ..       ..       ..
y1   value11  value12  value13
y2   value21   null    value23
```

Currently I am using a [pivot table with dynamic columns](http://sqlhints.com/2014/03/18/dynamic-pivot-in-sql-server/) but I am getting this:

```
COL1   X1        X2       X3
..     ..        ..       ..
y1   value11    null     null
y1    null    value12    null
y1    null      null    value13
y2   value21    null     null
y2    null      null    value23
```

Please note that I dont need an agregate function like in the example. Let me know if you need some more details.

Comment: A common way to deal with this is just use a meaningless aggregation operator. Even if you don't NEED any aggregation, you can still use a group by on your Y values, and do, say, max() on the columns you create.

Comment: The RDBMS or DBA answer to this is to handle this in your report software and return the data as it exists in the table.  This is a display problem, not a data problem, so it's the application's job to handle it.  That may not be feasible since most report writing software is complete crap, but the difficulty of denormalizing data like this is partially due to this philosophy. The `PIVOT` statement was meant almost exclusively for well known financial period aggregation. I'm not saying, "You can't do it this way," I'm just explaining why it's so difficult.

Comment: @Xedni I am using that approach but I am getting only one value per row like: id1, valA, null, null; id1, null, valB, null. I am wondering if there is a way to merge all rows with save id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(COL1 VARCHAR(50),COL2 VARCHAR(50),COL3 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'y1', 'x1', 'value11'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'y1', 'x2', 'value12'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'y1', 'x3', 'value13'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'y2', 'x1', 'value21'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'y2', 'x3', 'value23'
```

Get the columns for pivot

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COL2 + ']', '[' + COL2 + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY COL2
```

Apply `CROSS JOIN` to get  `x1, x2, x3` for all `y` values. Then use LEFT JOIN to the same table to identify each `y` has `x1, x2` or `x3`. Now when pivoting, you will get the matrix in your desired manner.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT C1.*,T.COL3 
                 FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT DISTINCT T2.COL1,T1.COL2
                    FROM #TEMP T1
                    CROSS JOIN #TEMP T2
                 )C1
                 LEFT JOIN #TEMP T ON T.COL2 = C1.COL2 AND T.COL1 = C1.COL1
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(COL3)
                 FOR COL2 IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c39b0/1) to view result**

**EDIT :**

Do not use `CAST` or `CONVERT` while selecting columns for pivot. Do it inside the `pivot`.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + COL2 + ']', '[' + COL2 + ']')
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT COL2 FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY COL2

DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                 SELECT DISTINCT C1.*,CAST(T.COL3 AS INT) COL3 
                 FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT DISTINCT T2.COL1,T1.COL2
                    FROM #TEMP T1
                    CROSS JOIN #TEMP T2
                 )C1
                 LEFT JOIN TEMP T ON T.COL2 = C1.COL2 AND T.COL1 = C1.COL1
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(COL3)
                 FOR COL2 IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2f510/4) to view result**

Comment: Why? What happened? @sillo01

Comment: I forgot to mention all colums are int. I am using other method to set '@cols' as [x1],[x2],[x3],... but I am getting an error compiling '@query'

Comment: I can't see any of the columns of type **int** in your question. Do u mean that **value11**, **value12** etc are actually **int** values? @sillo01

Comment: yes it is. Actually I am working only with integer columns. I have already updated the question to clarify that. Anyway thank you for your support, your answer is just what I want but I can't make it work with my data.